# In a singly linked list how do you shift to the right?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a class linkedList, which contains the head, tail, and size variables. In this class, I have a shift method, which shifts to the right if the number in the method parameter(shiftAmount) is positive, and to the left, if negative. I understand how to shift to the left but am confused about how to shift right without a prev pointer.

```
public void shift(int shiftAmount) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null) {
        return;
    }
    if(shiftAmount < 0) {
        shiftAmount = shiftAmount * -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < shiftAmount; i++) {
            Node temp;
            temp = head;
            head = head.next;
            temp.next = null;
            tail.next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }
    else {
        // how do I shift to the right????????
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, as it's a singly linked list.  Each node has a single link, to the next node.  You would need to make a doubly linked list instead if you want to be able to go both ways.  Look at how your code assigns the .next item for each node, and replicate to create a .previous reference as well.

Comment: If you really want to do this with a single linked list then you could create a new instance of your linkedList with the tail or a new element at the head which would be the same as a right shift?

Comment: You could create a linked list and push to head each node as you traverse the list, then you could go backwards. But it's an odd requirement for a singly linked list.

Answer (score 2):

If by "shift" you mean "rotate", such that the values at the ends roll over to the beginning, then it's easy enough.

E.g. say we have the list `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]`. Here are some examples of "shifts":

```java
shift(0):  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
shift(1):  [11, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
shift(3):  [7, 9, 11, 1, 3, 5]
shift(5):  [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 1]
shift(6):  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
shift(-1): [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 1]
```

As you can see, for a size of 6, shifting 6 right is the same as shifting 0, and shifting 5 right is the same as shifting 1 left.

You can *normalize* the shift value by calculating modulus size, i.e. `shift % size`. E.g. for size 6, that will result in a shift value in the range -5 to +5. You can eliminate the left shifts by adding the size and calculating modulus again, i.e. `(shift + size) % size`. Combined that means:

```java
int normalizedShift = (shift % size + size) % size;
```

If the normalized shift is 0, stop. You're done.

Otherwise we need to grab the last `normalizedShift` nodes and move them up front.

If you draw it, a `shift(2)` looks like this:

```
         BEFORE
head                tail
↓                   ↓
1 → 3 → 5 → 7 → 9 → 11

         AFTER
               tail   head
               ↓      ↓
┌→ 1 → 3 → 5 → 7      9 → 11 ─┐
└─────────────────────────────┘
```

Which is done as follow:

```java
tail.next = head;
//    head                tail
//    ↓                   ↓
// ┌→ 1 → 3 → 5 → 7 → 9 → 11 ─┐
// └──────────────────────────┘

for (int i = 0; i < size - normalizedShift - 1)
    head = head.next;
//                head    tail
//                ↓       ↓
// ┌→ 1 → 3 → 5 → 7 → 9 → 11 ─┐
// └──────────────────────────┘

tail = head;
head = head.next;
//                tail  head
//                ↓     ↓
// ┌→ 1 → 3 → 5 → 7  →  9 → 11 ─┐
// └────────────────────────────┘

tail.next = null;
//                tail  head
//                ↓     ↓
// ┌→ 1 → 3 → 5 → 7     9 → 11 ─┐
// └────────────────────────────┘
```

All-in-all:

```java
public void shift(int shiftAmount) {
    int normalizedShift = (shiftAmount % size + size) % size;
    if (normalizedShift != 0) {
        tail.next = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - normalizedShift - 1; i++)
            head = head.next;
        tail = head;
        head = head.next;
        tail.next = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a single linked list you can not shift to the right.
Just replace `shiftAmount` shift to the right by `size - shiftAmount` shift to the left.